# Is it possible .htaccess on WordPress without plug in

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a wordpress website which is manjeri.net it doesn't show www before the domain name.
I know how to use .htaccess. Is there any option on WordPress dashboard. I'm just beginner on wordpress.

Comment: You can pick up and edit the `.htaccess` file in your wordpress root directory, that is if you can access that folder.

Comment: It's not clear from the question, do you want to redirect from `manjeri.net` to `www.manjeri.net`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do with just a simple method

Go to WP admin panel settings there is URL option
add www behind your domain name then save that's it 
enjoy WP :)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to edit your .htaccess manually for this.

In your admin panel under Settings, update the "WordPress address (URL)" and "Site address (URL)" to have the "www".

Comment: Does this create some kind of redirect (either .htaccess or Wordpress)?

Comment: Yes. Internally, Wordpress will check this and redirect if necessary. I'd strongly suggest avoiding editing your .htaccess on CMS installs unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: OK, but wouldn't it be much faster to redirect at the server level than loading Wordpress just to redirect?

Comment: Bad times ahead if you change the .htaccess without changing it in WordPress as it'll enter a redirect loop. The time it takes to redirect won't be noticed by users.

Answer (score 0):

Try pasting the following code into your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.manjeri.net$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.manjeri.net/$1 [R=301]
```

- This should add www to your domain. (*Note: you may want to rename to htacess.txt before downloading to your computer for editing. Some computers hide files that start with a dot. Then rename to .htaccess after you re-upload it.*)

Comment: Don't literal dots in regex need to be prefaced with a backslash?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would put in my .htaccess to redirect non-www to www:

```
# redirect all non-www traffic
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^manjeri\.net$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.manjeri.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Edit:** If you want to edit your .htaccess file from the WP dashboard, check out this thread:

[Plugin to edit htaccess file](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1890/plugin-to-edit-htaccess-file)

You could also use a plugin like WordPress SEO, it lets you edit .htaccess as well.